# AS400 Define Query Results Convert a character field in to numeric and calculate

Tags: ibm-midrange

AS400 Define Query Results, Convert a character field in to numeric and calculate

In AS400 wrkqry and where i define query results i want to do following.

Character field from a PF with value 0,25 and convert it to a numeric field and add 1,0 so i get the results 1,25 in the numeric result field.

I cant change the physical file to make that field numeric.

Answer (score 1):

I've never tried it, but I've heard you can convert char to numeric via the  microsecond portion of a time stamp; then pull the microseconds back out as numeric.

Better solution would be to build a SQL View or DDS LF that converts the field to numeric; then use that in your Query/400 query.

Best solution, get rid of Query/400.  Use an SQL based query tool.  [IBM Db2 Web Query for i](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/ibm-db2-web-query-i) is the modern replacement for Query/400.

But even 20 years ago, IBM offered the SQL based Query Manager (STRQM) tool that offered a prompted mode similar to Query/400.

**edit**
found an [IBM doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/converting-character-field-numeric-query400) that has the Query/400 conversion hack.

```
Example 1: CHAR4 is a 4-digit character field in the file. Define the following result fields:

TIMESTAMP   TIMESTAMP('2003-01-01-00.00.00.00'||CHAR4)

NUMERIC     MICROSECOND(TIMESTAMP)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Ref. [IBM doc](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/converting-character-field-numeric-query400)**

**Example 1:** CHAR4 is a 4-digit character field in the file. Define the following result fields:

```
TIMESTAMP   TIMESTAMP('2003-01-01-00.00.00.00'||CHAR4)

NUMERIC     MICROSECOND(TIMESTAMP)
```

**Example 2:** CHAR6 is a 6-digit character field in the file. Define the following result fields:

```
TIMESTAMP   TIMESTAMP('2003-01-01-00.00.00.' || CHAR6)

TIMESTAMP2  timestamp(timestamp)

NUMERIC     microsecond(timestamp2)
```

The newly created NUMERIC field will be a BINARY data type.